# PayPal IPN empty when buying by card

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have tested a PayPal IPN on sandbox. It works without issue. I tested it using the demo PayPal account. Now I have moved live I cannot test with a PayPal account, as I only have one. So I tried using a card. The payment is successfully made. However, the IPN is empty.

I don't have any PHP errors for the IPN call. The IPN URL defined in Notifications -> Payment Notifications on my live account is correct.

The payment is made using PayPal Smart Checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/#how-the-buttons-work

Does PayPal not use IPNs when buying by card?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be directed to PayPal and is not about computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

What do you need IPN for? That is a very old service.

Use a server-side integration for the PayPal Checkout. Here's the UI: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

You'll need two corresponding routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Comment: It can work, if configured and used properly. Apparently it hasn't been. But more importantly, it's an old piece of technology that you shouldn't be bothering with in the first place unless you have a clear need for it.